# Python 3.6 and Pip - How to resolve textract and chardet version incompatibility?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, homebrew

I've installed Python 3.x and Pip on my Mac via Homebrew (`brew install python`). However I think something is wrong with my Pip installation because whenever I try to install a package (like `pip3 install pytest`), I see the following error message:

```
textract 1.6.1 has requirement chardet==2.3.0, but you'll have chardet 3.0.4 which is incompatible.
```

Or is this just a versioning issue with the underlying packages?

And how can I resolve these package version issues?

Comment: A bit trite - but use virtual environments, seems like [`pipenv`](https://docs.pipenv.org/) has become a [sanctioned](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/#managing-dependencies) way of doing this.

Comment: Yes this is a version issue. Why not remove `chardet`?

Comment: @AChampion thanks, I do like Pipenv, but I'm trying to resolve this underlying issue if possible.

Comment: @Sraw I ran `pip3 uninstall chardet` but when I tried installing other packages again, I ran into the same error: "textract 1.6.1 has requirement chardet==2.3.0, but you'll have chardet 3.0.4 which is incompatible."

Comment: Also, if I run `pip3 install chardet==2.3.0` and then try to install another package, I get errors like "requests 2.18.4 has requirement chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2, but you'll have chardet 2.3.0 which is incompatible.". Can't seem to win :-)

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with textract on myriad of different libraries: argcomplete, beautifulsoup4, EbookLib, and others.

Comment: Although I continue to see the same error, it looks like the packages I'm trying to install are getting installed.

Comment: Which version of chardet is compatible for 'textract 1.6.1'